# Autocomplete selection in Rules Component

Tags: 7, rules, views

How do I create a rules component which lets you select or autocomplete a node from an existing list of nodes?

I have tried all the Data Type while creating a Rule Component. Each one of them requires a direct input rather than a Drop Down Select List or Autocomplete function.

Please advice

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that your question is related to ***executing*** a Rules Component, and not ***creating*** it.

A possible approach might be to *process the results of a [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) enabled view via [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)*, whereas your rule performs 2 Rules Actions:

- load the VBO list of entities (such as nodes) that you want to be processed.
- add a loop to perform a Rules Action, for each entity (such as a node) contained in your Views results.

For more details, have a look at the tutorial "[How to process the results of a VBO enabled view via Rules?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/90)".

Comment: I am able to create the Rule Component and also execute it, Thanks to you @Pierre for guiding me with a similar issue in the past, it helped me to get this done. What I presently need is in the execution of the rule, I need a drop down or autoselect list of the chosen fields. At the moment all are coming as direct input for the user.